# Manipulating Boolean value used for While loops from function in separate document

Tags: python, variables, import, boolean, pylance

I am just building a simple program and I'm encountering a variable not being "accessed" according to Pylance.

I understand that this usually happens for deadcode.

Here is what I have:

Main program file.

```
player_turn = True

while true:
    #some code
```

I in a separate file for just logic functions I have something like this.

```
def some_func():
    #if some condition
        player_turn = False
```

However, in my function file, pylance is telling me that 'player_turn is not accessed.'

I've imported the variable from my main program into my function file.

And my functions from said file are properly being imported into my main program file.

Any suggestions? Ready to learn something new here!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
while true:
```

Is not correct
Correct code is

```
while player_turn
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that should be mentioned is that a `while True` loop never terminates without a `break` statement.

```
while True:
    if some_condition is meet: <- conditional statement
        break # <- without this any following_code will not be accessed.

... following_code
```

Another problem is that immutable data defined in the global scope cannot be edited inside a function.  For example:

```
a = 5 

def change_a():
    a = 10 # <- this doesn't change a outside of the function. All this
           # does is define a new variable `a` within the function
           # scope which when the function exits will be destroyed
           # not effecting any variables of the same name outside
           # of the function.
 
print(a) # outputs "5"
```

If I were to remove the print statement, pylance would say `a` was never accessed.